# Managing different objects in GWT-OSGi

Tags: gwt, osgi

I am integrating a GWT application into an OSGi environment with different bundles. To be honest, I am not expert in Graphical User Interfaces and GWT development, so, maybe I am trying to do anything which is not possible. Within the OSGi environment, I am using the event communication procedure. In this way, the GWT project sends an event to a database communicator bundle based on Hibernate. Then, the database connector responses with another event whose properties contain one related to a list of objects as follows:

```
List<KpiDesc> lKPIs = (List<KpiDesc>)event.getProperty("KPIlist");
```

This list contains objects whose type is com.cartif.hibernatemappings.KpiDesc. However, this package is internal of the database connector and if I try to make use of it in the client side of GWT I get an error. Trying to solve it, I have copied the same object in the shared package of the GWT project to avoid compilation error and I would like to cast one object to another. The code for such prupose is the next:

```
List<com.cartif.gui.optimization.shared.KpiDesc> lKPIs2 = new ArrayList<com.cartif.gui.optimization.shared.KpiDesc>();
for(int i = 0; i < lKPIs.size(); i++){
    lKPIs2.add(new KpiDesc(lKPIs.get(i).getKpiId(), lKPIs.get(i).getName(), lKPIs.get(i).getDescription(),lKPIs.get(i).getDefinition(), lKPIs.get(i).getBuildingName()));
}
```

Nevertheless, in the creation of the new object (call to the constructor), the code delegates in the EventManager and there is no response. Do you know how I could manage different objects?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: How you are returning the objects to client from server?Can you post it

Comment: Well, I create a HashMap<String, List> where the key is a parameter I'm internally using and the aforementioned List. This is the return type in the Asynchronous call from the client. I mean, the onSuccess method return object is similar to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I could manage to solve this issue. It is divided in two parts:

- Compilation mode

First of all, for compiling, I had to create the file .gwt.xml within the package where the java clases are. The file looks like

```
<module>
    <source path="">
         <include name="**/KpiDesc.java"/>
    </source>
</module>
```

Then, in the .gwt.xml file of the GWT project, I added the following line:

```
<inherits name='package.DWHC'/>
```

Last but not least, I included the project with the Java classes to be used into the build path of the GWT project as project reference.

- Operation mode

With the aforementioned procedure, I could compile the project and, then, make use of the KpiDesc object in the server side. However, it does not work in the client side. Hence, from the operational point of view, I had to create a similar object in the shared package of GWT project (with different name) and, in the server side, map the original object from Hibernate to the new object of GWT.

I hope this could also help others who experiment the same troubles.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention where you create the new shared objects. You should create them in the persistence layer where you have access to the internal classes. You should then send the event with the shared classes. This way it should work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you! If you mention the internal GWT objects, these are in the "shared" package. Or you mean in the "DatabaseBundle". In both projects, the object is replicated and what I want is: 1 - make use of the object in the "DatabaseBundle" or 2 - Translate it into an internal new object

Comment: Now I am totally confused. I understood that you have internal classes that are not exported by the DataBaseBundle and shared classes that are exported. In this case it is quite natural that do the mapping from internal classes to shared classes in the databsebundle as only this bundde has access to both the internal classes as well as the shared ones.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation if I caused confusion :) Well, the idea is that the DB-bundle uses Hibernate, and it retrieves a list of "Hibernate" objects into an OSGi event which is received by the GUI based on GWT. My question is how to make use of these objects or, at least, how to cast them. Thank you so much

Comment: If you simply want to access the persistence entity classes then export the relevant packges in the bundle that defines them and import the package where you need them. In case of hibernate you have to make sure that collections are pre fetched as you will access them outside the hibernate session when you use the objects from the UI.

Comment: But, if I import/export these packages by means of the manifest, I cannot compile the GWT project because it requires to inherit a module.

Comment: In that case you might need to have extra UI data classes and have to copy them from the shared classes. So the code you have in your question should work if the shared classes are exported / imported.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75933/discussion-between-jose-hdez-and-christian-schneider).